# PHP File request from url directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

This is probably a very easy question. Anyway how do you use variables from a url without requests. For example:

```
www.mysite.com/get.php/id/123
```

Then the page retrieves id 123 from a database.

How is this done? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

If i have the following structure:

```
support/
        sys/
            issue/
                  issue.php
            .htaccess
            home.php
            etc.....
```

With .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/issue/(.*)$ /issue/issue.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Why do I have to type:

> http://www.mysite.com/support/sys/issue/issue/1234

In order to load a file? When I want to type

> http://www.mysite.com/support/sys/issue/1234

also, how do I then retrieve the id once the file loads?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

This is a very basic/common problem which stems from the fact that your `.htaccess` rule is rewriting a url which contains a directory which actually exists...

#### File structure

```
>support
    >sys
        >issue
            issue.php
        .htaccess
```

(I.e. the directory `issue` and the `.htaccess` file are in the same directory: `sys`)

#### Rewrite Issues

Then:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^issue/(.*)/*$ issue/issue.php?id=$1 [L]
# Note the added /* before $. In case people try to access your url with a trailing slash
```

Will not work. This is because (Note: `->` = redirects to):
http://www.mysite.com/support/sys/issue/1234
-> http://www.mysite.com/support/sys/issue/issue.php?id=1234
-> http://www.mysite.com/support/sys/issue/issue.php?id=issue.php

#### Example/Test

Try it with `var_dump($_GET)` and the following URLs:

- http://mysite.com/support/sys/issue/1234
- http://mysite.com/support/sys/issue/issue.php

Output will always be:

```
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(9) "issue.php" }
```

### Solution

You have *three* main options:

1. Add a condition that *real files* aren't redirected
2. Only rewrite numbers e.g. rewrite `issue/123` but not `issue/abc`
3. Do both

#### Method 1

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^issue/(.*)/*$ issue/issue.php?id=$1 [L]
```

#### Method 2

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^issue/(\d*)/*$ issue/issue.php?id=$1 [L]
```

#### Method 3

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^issue/(\d*)/*$ issue/issue.php?id=$1 [L]
```

---

### Retrieving the ID

This is the simple part...

```
$issueid = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess you should add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /get.php/?id=$1 [L]
```

Also like previous posters mentioned, make sure you have your mod_rewrite activated.

Comment: What have you tried? This are pretty much basics, I warmly suggest you head over to http://php.net/manual/en/index.php and start reading on things like http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a file called `.htaccess`, do a search on Google and you'll find a lot of examples how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (or the equivalent on your platform) to rewrite `/get.php/id/123` to `/get.php?id=123`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `PATH_INFO` `$_SERVER` variable.

From http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php:

> 'PATH_INFO'
>
> Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual
>   script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For
>   instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL
>   http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then
>   $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain /some/stuff.

`explode()` it and work on its parts.

**EDIT**: Use rewrite rules to map the users' request URLs to your internal structure and/or hide the script name. But **not** to convert the `PATH_INFO` to a `GET` query, that's totally unnecessary! Just do a `explode('/',$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])` and you're there!

Also, seeing your own answer, you don't need any `preg_math`es. If your database only contains numeric ids, giving it a non-numeric one will simply be rejected. If for some reason you still need to check if a string var has a numeric value, consider [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

*Keep it simple. Don't reinvent the wheel!*

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried the `.htaccess` method but to no avail. So I attempted a PHP solution and came up with this.

issue.php

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'issue.php') !== FALSE){
    $url = split('issue.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'issue') !== FALSE){
    $url = split('issue/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else{
    exit("URI REQUESET ERROR"); 
}

$id = $url[1];

if(preg_match('/[^0-9]/i', $id)) {
    exit("Invalid ID");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why no answer has mentioned you about use of [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

As per Apache manual:

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for
>   per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a
>   relative path.

Using `RewriteBase` in your `/support/sys/issue/.htaccess`, code will be simply:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /support/sys/issue/

RewriteRule ^([0-9+)/?$ issue.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then insde your `issue.php` you can do:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

to retrieve your id from URL.